# Entity Framework 4 merge data to tracked entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first

I'm struggling with Entity Framework code first and merging.
I have an MVC controller with a generic repository. A view model gets posted up and I convert that into the type that EF knows about

```
    var converted = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<RoutineViewModel, Routine>(result);
    _routineRepository.Update(converted);
```

In the repository I have:

```
/*   
            Routines.Attach(item);
            ChangeTracker.Entries<Routine>().Single(x => x.Entity.Id == item.Id).State = EntityState.Modified;*/
            var match = Routines.Single(x => x.Id == item.Id);
            var entity = Entry(match);

            entity.CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
```

I commented out the first bit because it was throwing an error about already tracking the entity even though a check like this:

```
if (ChangeTracker.Entries<Routine>().Count(x => x.Entity.Id == item.Id) != 0)
```

returned false

The problem I'm having is that the Routine object has an ICollection property of Steps. When I set the values of the tracked entity to match that of the poco the ICollection changes aren't propagated down. Looking around this site there looks to be a few nasty looking recursive calls. Is this really how it works or am I missing something?

Is there any easy way to say, here is the source object (untracked), copy everything about it into the tracked object?

Just to be clear I don't think that getting the object first and updating the properties on that should be done outside of the repository. That seems to not only force you to pass your data models across domain boundaries but seems like instead of an equivalent SQL like statement being (update x,y where id = 1), to (insert into temp table where id = 1, for reach row in temp table, update x..... now for each row in table update table x = tempx where id = 1)

Edit --
So the problem is with the setValues not being a recursive call. The routine object has 2 simple properties (id and name) and one complex (ICollection ). If the item coming in has the name changed and some steps changed, setValues picks up the name change but doesn't apply to the children. Is there some other way to do this? It seems a little creaky to me that I have to hand roll this functionality

Answer (score 0):

From what i can tell you are creating your entity, populating properties and then attaching it to the DB. This is kinda the wrong way round with EF.

If you want to attach an object which is already in the DB but isnt being tracked, you can use attach but only changes made after the attach call are recorded to be committed to the DB. If you want to use attach make sure you make your changes after calling that method.

In addition EF only allows you to attach an object which is not currently in the object graph. So if you try to attach the same object twice (or one with the same key) you will be given an error such as the one you are seeing.

Comment: Hi Luke,Thanks for the info but I shouldn't have to retrieve the entity from the repository, modify it and then commit it just because its' EF. My assumption was that the SetValues would basically do a recursive compare on all the properties and assign any to the tracked entity that didn't match. As to the commented out code that throws the error the object isn't attached (see the change tracker call below the main code block) and neither are any of it's child properties as the entity has been created completely from scratch, yet the error still occurs.

Comment: If you are creating brand new entities the normal method is to use Routines.Add(myNewRoutine), attach is for reattaching objects which already exist in the DB but haven't yet been loaded onto the object graph.

Comment: Hi Luke, 
I've left out a bit of code on purpose, but I have an insert method which calls Routines.Add(item); with no problem. This is just to deal with an update scenario